# How does std::string overload the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, stdstring

```
class mystring { 
private:
 string s;
public:
 mystring(string ss) { 
  cout << "mystring : mystring() : " + s <<endl; 
  s = ss;
 }
 /*! mystring& operator=(const string ss) { 
  cout << "mystring : mystring& operator=(string) : " + s <<endl;
  s = ss; 
  //! return this; 
  return (mystring&)this; // why COMPILE ERROR
 } */
 mystring operator=(const string ss) {
  cout << "mystring : mystring operator=(string) : " + s <<endl;
  s = ss;
  return *this;
 } 
 mystring operator=(const char ss[]) {
  cout << "mystring : mystring operator=(char[]) : " << ss <<endl;
  s = ss;
  return *this;
 }
};

mystring str1 =  "abc"; // why COMPILE ERROR
mystring *str2 = new mystring("bcd");
```

So the questiones are

1. how to make a correct mystring& opeartor= overload?That is,how could I return a reference rather than a pointer?(could we tranfer between reference and pointer in C++?)
2. how to make a correct mystring operator= overload?I thought the source code would work fine,but it turns out I still could not assign const char[] to mystring as if I didn't overload the operator=.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a 'conversion' constructor that takes a `const char*`:

```
mystring( char const* ss) {
  cout << "mystring : mystring(char*) ctor : " << ss <<endl;
  s = ss;
}
```

The line you're having a problem with:

```
mystring str1 =  "abc"; // why COMPILE ERROR
```

isn't really an assignment - it's an initializer.

Comment: He needs both if he wants to perform assignment on preexisting objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
mystring& operator=(const string &ss) 
{
    cout << "mystring : mystring operator=(string) : " + s <<endl;
    s = ss;

    return *this; // return the reference to LHS object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `"string"` has `const char *` type and you should overload assignment operator for it.

```
mystring& operator=(const char * s);
```

To get a reference from a pointer `*this` is suffice, no need to cast anything.

Comment: Did Russel delete his answer?

Comment: Hm, yes, he did for some reason.

Comment: `"string"` has type `const char[7]`, not `const char *`. As for the assignment operator, yes, it should be overloaded for `const char *`, which is the type the array will decay to.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mystring& operator=(const string& ss) {
  cout << "mystring : mystring operator=(string) : " << s << endl;
  s = ss;

  return *this;
 } 
 mystring& operator=(const char* const pStr) {
  cout << "mystring : mystring operator=(zzzz) : " << pStr << endl;
  s = pStr;

  return *this;
 }
```

- I added '&' to your strings so it
  returns a reference to 'this' and not
  a copy of it (it's good practice to
  do that for the input parameter too
  as you're then not uneccessarily making a
  copy of the input string),
- I swapped    a '+' to '<<' in line 2
- and I    altered your array to a
  *const char*    const* pointer